# Celery task not counted as 'succeeded' for multiple minutes after returning

Tags: django, heroku, celery, django-celery

I have a celery task (running as part of a Django app) which typically takes about ~5 seconds. Mostly, it works great, and after a few seconds when I query it with `AsyncResult` I get `SUCCESS` as the state. Occasionally, however, it seems that there is a VERY long lag between the task returning (as tested by putting log statements right before the return statement of the function called by the task) and celery acknowledging it as successful (as noted by Celery logging something like:

`Task dynamicapp.tasks.myTask[090422da-184c-40ce-8d5d-3dcba6680219] succeeded in 129.666630374s`.

As you can see, this is ~2 minutes, even though the function itself returned after the usual  ~5 seconds. On occasion, I've even seen this take ~15 minutes to acknowledge as 'succeeded.'

I'm using Celery 4.0 and deploying the Django app on Heroku, for what its worth.

*EDIT:*

Output of `celery report` below:

```
software -> celery:4.0.0 (latentcall) kombu:4.0.0 py:2.7.11
        billiard:3.5.0.2 py-amqp:2.1.1
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
settings -> transport:amqp results:disabled
```

This is really interesting because it looks like the `results:disabled` might be the culprit...and yet, when I deploy to Heroku, results are enabled and look like they're working (see log below):

```
Nov 24 04:28:56 myApp app/worker.2:  -- * - **** ---  
Nov 24 04:28:56 myApp app/worker.2:  - ** ---------- [config] 
Nov 24 04:28:56 myApp app/worker.2:  - ** ---------- .> app:         dynamicapp:0x7fe829e2cad0 
Nov 24 04:28:56 myApp app/worker.2:  - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://h:**@<my redis>// 
Nov 24 04:28:56 myApp app/worker.2:  - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://h:**@<my redis>/ 
Nov 24 04:28:56 myApp app/worker.2:  - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork) 
Nov 24 04:28:56 myApp app/worker.2:  -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker) 
Nov 24 04:28:56 myApp app/worker.2:  --- ***** -----  
Nov 24 04:28:56 myApp app/worker.2:   -------------- [queues] 
Nov 24 04:28:56 myApp app/worker.2:                  .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

*EDIT 2:*

Output of `celery -A <project> report` - this pulls from my main  `settings.py` so Celery-specific parts shown below:

```
software -> celery:4.0.0 (latentcall) kombu:4.0.0 py:2.7.11
            billiard:3.5.0.2 redis:2.10.5
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
settings -> transport:redis results:redis://h:**@<my redis>/

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT: ['json']
CACHES: {
    'default': {   'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
                   'LOCATION': <my redis>',
                   'OPTIONS': {   'DB': 0, 'PASSWORD': u'********'}}}
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES: 300
CELERY_INCLUDE: ['dynamicapp.tasks']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER: 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: 'redis://h:********@<my redis>/'
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD: 2
BROKER_URL: 'redis://h:********@<my redis>//'
```

Comment: What task related settings you have in your celery config? Can you please add `celery -A <project> report` result in your question ?

Comment: @ssudake See edit - that seems to point to results:disabled as the culprit, but I'm not sure why that's happening since it starts off enabled

Comment: There should be some configuration fault regarding `result_backend`. It is also  possible  `result_backend` in set in your worker but not in task calling module.

Comment: @ssudake I think that may be a red herring though - as I mentioned, the task *does* succeed, it just takes a few minutes for some reason even though every other time it succeeds in a few seconds. I *think* this might be to do with writing to the Redis result backend being hung up for some reason, but have no idea how to test this

Comment: You have shared output of `celery report`. Please share output of `celery -A <project> report`, where <project> is your celery project name.

Comment: Added. I've also noticed that when the task takes a while to succeed, it 'officially' succeeds almost exactly 120 seconds after I see my log output from right before the task should be returning. I'm not sure if this is some weird caching behavior in querying the task state - I'm checking every second by calling `tasks.myTask.AsyncResult(taskId).state`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128961/discussion-between-ssudake-and-amn).